# Counting consecutive duplicates of strings from a list

Tags: python, arrays, string, list, duplicates

I have a Python list of strings such that,

Input:

```
li = ['aaa','bbb','aaa','abb','abb','bbb','bbb','bbb','aaa','aaa']
```

What can I do to generate another list counting the number of consecutive repetitions of any string in the list? For the list above the return list resembles:

Expected Output:

```
li_count = [['aaa',1],['bbb',1]['abb',2],['bbb',3],['aaa',2]]
```

Comment: Didn't you forget the second, not duplicated 'aaa'? `li_count = [['aaa',1],['bbb',1],['aaa',1],['abb',2],['bbb',3],['aaa,2]]` should be correct. And please, show what your attempts look like so far and why do they not work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
from itertools import groupby
li = ['aaa','bbb','aaa','abb','abb','bbb','bbb','bbb','aaa','aaa']

a = [[i, sum(1 for i in group)] for i, group in groupby(li)]
print(a)
[['aaa', 1], ['bbb', 1], ['aaa', 1], ['abb', 2], ['bbb', 3], ['aaa', 2]]
```

Thank you @user3483203 for improvement:

```
a = [[i, len([*group])] for i, group in groupby(li)]
```

Comment: It is a lot faster here to use `[[i, len([*group])] for i, group in groupby(li)]`.  About twice as fast as `sum`