# Count consecutive duplicate values in ArrayList (Kotlin)

Tags: kotlin

I would like to determine the number of consecutive duplicate Strings in an ArrayList in Kotlin.
What I have is something along the lines of:
`val array: ArrayList<String> = arrayListOf("training", "training", "assessment", "training", "assessment", "assessment")`

Where the output I want is something that counts the consecutive duplicate elements like:
`[["training", "2"], ["assessment", "1"], ["training", "1"], ["assessment", "2"]` or something simpler/cleaner.
I have found a similar solution in Python [Counting consecutive duplicates of strings from a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50829381/counting-consecutive-duplicates-of-strings-from-a-list). But I am looking for a Kotlin version. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could manually build the list, like this:

```
fun count(values: List<String>): List<Group> {
    val groups = mutableListOf<Group>()
    values.forEach {
        val last = groups.lastOrNull()
        if (last?.value == it) {
            last.count++
        } else {
            groups.add(Group(it, 1))
        }
    }
    return groups
}

data class Group(val value: String, var count: Int)
```

This results in:

```
[Group(value=training, count=2), Group(value=assessment, count=1), Group(value=training, count=1), Group(value=assessment, count=2)]
```

Comment: Exactly what I am looking for, thanks @CampbellMG! Made my whole function a lot cleaner :)